# Could not resolve placeholder 'database.dags.driverClassName'

Tags: spring, postgresql

Im trying to create an application that access a postgres database using Spring. When I run the application following error occur.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dagsDataSource' defined in file [F:\Spring_Batch_Project\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringBatchAdmin\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\batch\override\dataSource-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.dags.driverClassName'
```

Here is my datasource.context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>com/dirbi/oracle/resources/dbconfig/database.properties</value>
        </property>

    </bean>



    <!-- DAGs DataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="dagsDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driver" value="${database.dags.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.dags.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.dags.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.dags.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Batch DataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="springBatchDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driver" value="${database.springbatch.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.springbatch.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.springbatch.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.springbatch.password}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is database.properties

```
database.dags.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.dags.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/testing
database.dags.username=postgres
database.dags.password=admin

database.springbatch.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.springbatch.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/springbatchadmindb
database.springbatch.username=postgres
database.springbatch.password=admin
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since Spring 3.1 `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` isn't recommended - use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead, or just `<context:property-placeholder/>`.

Second: `com/dirbi/oracle/resources/dbconfig/database.properties` isn't enough.
You have to specify the `resource type prefix`. Typically `classpath:`, but it depends of where your file is located. If it just within some dir you should use `file://`.
However it looks like your `database.properties` is in the some package, so use `classpath:`.

BTW, why `/oracle/`, if you use `PostgreSQL` ?

Comment: Bilanz: Firstly thank you very much for your answer. Where I write <context:property-placeholder/>? For why /oracle/, if you use PostgreSQL ? This package name is given by my friend, I don't know exactly which DB use.

Comment: `<context:property-placeholder/>` instead of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean definition. By your main issue is `classpath:` prefix for the `location` value